# siunitx and unusual seriesdefault

Tags: siunitx

I have a font setup which adds a light series and declares this to be the default (in the MWE below the light series is represented by a helvica font). I can't find a way to setup siunitx so that it uses in text mode this default series and still reacts *locally*  to the `detect-weight` option (setting `detect-weight` globally is my current work around).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{detect-mode}

\normalfont
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{cmr}{lt}{n}{<->phvr7t}{}
\renewcommand\seriesdefault{lt}
\providecommand\lseries{\fontseries{lt}\selectfont}

\begin{document}

Middle column wrong

abc \SI{1}{\meter} \SI[detect-weight]{1}{\meter}

\bfseries 
abc \SI{1}{\meter} \SI[detect-weight]{1}{\meter}

\bigskip
Last cell wrong

\sisetup{text-rm=\normalfont}

abc \SI{1}{\meter} \SI[detect-weight]{1}{\meter}

\bfseries
abc \SI{1}{\meter} \SI[detect-weight]{1}{\meter}

\end{document}
```

[image]